# chain cUrl PHP output

Tags: php, curl

how to do after submitting a form using cUrl PHP (all ready done this) the problem is the output got pagination, how to do in cUrl to click or trigger the next page on result of the previous cUrl call?

Answer (score 0):

Examine the results page. Chances are the page number is set from a GET parameter, like this

```
example.com/results?page=2
example.com/results?page=3
...etc
```

Once you figure out the pattern, just cURL the URL with an incrementing counter until you encounter a 404 error

Comment: the url does not change cuz the site i scrap with is ASP.net.. so basically the only way is to get that previous output then run again the curl_exec but i cant find away to do that...

Comment: There has to be someway the site keeps a record of which page you are currently on. It has to be either via GET, POST, cookies (session), or it is simply displaying the result in batches via javascript. Try to figure out which is the case, or if possible, give the url so I can help you with that

Answer (score 0):

Use some network sniffer tools to figure out the actual ajax call behind the sense.
Firebug in Firefox might be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

After you get response from server, your output is paginated. There are at lease two options:
1. page is paginated on client side
2. page is paginated on server side

Probably second options is your case. All of pagination has unique url, i.e. they are different in some GET parameter:

```
{url}/page=1 <br>
{url}/page=2 <br>
```

So you have to catch request sending from page (i.e. in developer tools in chrome) and repeat these request in your cURL PHP script.